# Required to implement the business requirement by using CTC in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

It would be great help to implement the small `SP` for the following requirement.

Business rule is:

> EndDate should start date of next rule otherwise rule should not be
>   consider as continuous and would be treated a other rule series, as
>   shown in the below example there are two series because for fourth
>   record it has breaked.

```
RuleId  Name    StartDate           EndDate
2       TP1     1/1/2015 00.00.00   1/31/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     1/31/2015 00.00.00  2/28/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     2/28/2015 00.00.00  3/15/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     3/18/2015 00.00.00  3/28/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     3/28/2015 00.00.00  4/30/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     4/30/2015 00.00.00  5/5/2015 00.00.00
```

Result should be:

```
RuleId  Name    StartDate           EndDate
2       TP1     1/1/2015 00.00.00   3/15/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     3/18/2015 00.00.00  5/5/2015 00.00.00
```

Comment: Which version of sql server do you use?

Comment: Thanks.. Giorgi Nakeuri.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 and LEAD & LAG functions are not available there. Can you please suggest the solution for SQL Server 2008.  Please note one point " Last record EndDate value can be null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For Sql Server 2012+`:

```
with cte1 as (select *,
case when lag(enddate) over(partition by ruleid order by startdate) = startdate 
     then 0 else 1 end as b
from t),
cte2 as(select *, sum(b) over(partition by ruleid order by startdate) as s
from cte1)
select ruleid, name, min(startdate), max(enddate) from cte2
group by s, ruleid, name
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aadf4/1

For Sql Server 2008 use:

```
WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY startdate ) rn ,
                        CASE WHEN ( SELECT  MAX(enddate)
                                    FROM    @t ti
                                    WHERE   ti.ruleid = t.ruleid
                                            AND ti.startdate < t.startdate
                                  ) = startdate THEN 0
                             ELSE 1
                        END AS b
               FROM     @t t
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ( SELECT    SUM(b)
                          FROM      cte1 c11
                          WHERE     c11.ruleid = c1.ruleid
                                    AND c11.rn <= c1.rn
                        ) bb
               FROM     cte1 c1
             )
    SELECT  bb ,
            ruleid ,
            name ,
            MIN(startdate) ,
            CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(enddate) THEN MAX(enddate)
                 ELSE NULL
            END
    FROM    cte2
    GROUP BY bb ,
            ruleid ,
            name
```

Comment: Thanks for your g8 solution.  I am using SQL Server 2008 and Lag and Led functions are not available there. Can you please share the solution for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Hi, I have added requirement at question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911301/required-cte-implementation-for-hierarchical-data"

Answer (score 0):

**basing on your data and result we can proceed like this by using Month,Row_number function and using CTE**

```
declare @t table (RuleId  INT, Name  varchar(10),StartDate  datetime,Enddate datetime)

insert into @t (RuleId,Name,StartDate,Enddate)values (

2, 'TP1' ,'1/1/2015' ,'1/31/2015'),

(2, 'TP1', '1/31/2015' ,'2/28/2015'),

(2 ,'TP1', '2/28/2015', '3/15/2015'),

(2, 'TP1', '3/18/2015', '3/28/2015'),

(2, 'TP1', '3/28/2015', '4/30/2015'),

(2, 'TP1', '4/30/2015', '5/5/2015')
;with cte as (
select RuleId,
Name,
Startdate,
enddate,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(StartDate) ORDER BY MONTH(Enddate))R,
COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(ENDDATE) )RR from @t)
,cte2 as 
(
select RuleId,Name,Startdate,enddate,CASE WHEN RR <> R THEN R + 1 ELSE R END CR ,RR,R  from cte 
)
select RuleId,
Name,
CASE WHEN Sno = 1 THEN MIN(StartDate)
 WHEN Sno = 2 then MIN (StartDate) 
       ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN Sno = 1 THEN MAX(ENDDATE)
 WHEN Sno = 2 then MAX (ENDDATE) 
       ELSE '' END   from ( 
select RuleId,Name,StartDate,Enddate,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY RR,R ORDER BY CR)Sno from cte2 
where CR = R OR CR = RR ) K
GROUP BY  RuleId,Name,Sno
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I have one additional requirement that EndDate of last record can be null,  When I am using null Instead of '5/5/2015' then result out put is not expected. Can you please suggest the required changes.

Comment: i'm unable to understand what the result set you are expecting can you please modify that on in your question @PardumanDhiman

Comment: If I change the last record value by null
 
RuleId  Name    StartDate           EndDate

2       TP1     1/1/2015 00.00.00   1/31/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     1/31/2015 00.00.00  2/28/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     2/28/2015 00.00.00  3/15/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     3/18/2015 00.00.00  3/28/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     3/28/2015 00.00.00  4/30/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     4/30/2015 00.00.00  5/5/2015 00.00.00

Comment: Replace the Null Instead of last record EndDate "5/5/2015" Then Result should be like 
RuleId  Name    StartDate           EndDate

2       TP1     1/1/2015 00.00.00   3/15/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     3/18/2015 00.00.00  Null

Comment: WHEN Sno = 2 then MAX (ENDDATE)  replace it with WHEN Sno = 2 then NULL

Comment: I have tried, however not getting correct result. Please could you try at your end and share the changes.