# Required cte implementation for hierarchical data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Seeking optimized code for SQL Server 2008 (because `Lag` and `Lead` functions are not available in SQL Server 2008) only. For the following requirement.(Last record end date can be null or not null)

Business rule is:

EndDate should be start date for next rule otherwise rule should not be consider as continuous and would be treated a other rule series, as shown in the below example there are three series because for fourth record and 7 record rule has braked.

```
RuleId  Name    StartDate           EndDate
-----------------------------------------------------------    
2       TP1     1/1/2015 00.00.00   1/31/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     1/31/2015 00.00.00  2/28/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     2/28/2015 00.00.00  3/15/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     3/18/2015 00.00.00  11/28/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     11/28/2015 00.00.00 4/30/2016 00.00.00
2       TP1     4/30/2016 00.00.00  10/5/2016 00.00.00
2       TP1     10/25/2016 00.00.00  11/15/2016 00.00.00
2       TP1     11/15/2016 00.00.00  Null
```

Result should be following

```
2       TP1     1/1/2015 00.00.00  3/15/2015 00.00.00
2       TP1     3/18/2015 00.00.00 10/5/2016 00.00.00
2       TP1     10/25/2016 00.00.00  Null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY` and then do a self join with rn = rn + 1 and do a `DATEDIFF` based on which your can group your results.

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @Rules TABLE(RuleId  INT,Name CHAR(3),    StartDate DATE,           EndDate DATE)

INSERT INTO @Rules VALUES
(3 ,'TP3', '3/18/2015', '11/28/2015'),
(3 ,'TP3', '11/28/2015', '4/30/2016'),
(3 ,'TP3', '4/30/2016', '10/5/2016'),
(3 ,'TP3', '10/25/2016', '11/15/2016'),
(3 ,'TP3', '11/15/2016', null) 


;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RuleID ORDER BY StartDate) rn,*
FROM @Rules
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day,C1.EndDate,C2.StartDate),0) diff,C1.*
FROM CTE C1 
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.rn + 1 = C2.rn
 AND C1.RuleId = C2.RuleId
)
SELECT RuleId,Name,MIN(StartDate)  StartDate,NULLIF(MAX(CASE WHEN EndDate IS NULL THEN '2999/12/31' ELSE EndDate END),'2999/12/31') EndDate
FROM
(
SELECT C2.Diff,C1.RuleId,C1.Name,C1.StartDate,C1.EndDate
FROM CTE2 C1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Diff),0) Diff FROM CTE2 C2 WHERE C1.StartDate > C2.StartDate AND C1.RuleId = C2.RuleId) C2
) C
GROUP BY RuleId,Name,Diff
ORDER BY RuleId,Diff
```

Comment: Thanks for g8 solution, However when I am trying to test the same for following data range then first record is not considered
   (3       ,'TP3',     '3/18/2015',  '11/28/2015'),
(3       ,'TP3',     '11/28/2015', '4/30/2016'),
(3       ,'TP3',     '4/30/2016',  '10/5/2016'),
(3       ,'TP3',     '10/25/2016',  '11/15/2016'),
(3       ,'TP3',     '11/15/2016',  null)                                                                         
result start date is not expected